# Java calling a method without dot notation in an array

Tags: java

Can someone explain how the `getName()` and `getGrade()` end up referencing the same item as createProgressReport() without being told to?

It's clear that `createProgressReport` is called on the item in the array with `item.createProgressReport()`. But it seems like the `getName()` and `getGrade()` aren't told to be called on the same item since there is no dot notation like `item.getName()`.

How do the `getName()` and `getGrade()` methods seem to automatically "know" which student to call the method on.

```
for (Student item : myStudents) {
    System.out.println(item.createProgressReport());

public String createProgressReport() {
    String myString = getName() + " " + getGrade();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`createProgressReport` is called on an instance of an object.  Unless you are coding otherwise, any methods that get called within that method will be called on the same object.

To put it another way, your method is equivalent to:

```
String myString = this.getName() + " " + this.getGrade();
```

Comment: Dang, beat me to it just as I was typing the answer.

Comment: It's not a contest about speed.  It is up to the OP to decide which answer he prefers.

Comment: Very true. Well alls well that ends well!

Comment: Thanks Joe I think I get it. Since createProgressReport report was called on item, everything inside that method will be called on the same item unless otherwise specified? Right?

Answer (score 2):

To me it appears you are working within the context of a class.

In object oriented programming, calling a method from another method within a class will normally refer to the same instance.

Languages that may not perform this way are JavaScript or php, where you need a reference to the $this object.

```
//php
$this->methodName();

//JavaScript
var self = this;
self.methodName();

//java
methodName(); //implied this when working within the context of the same class
```